# How to fill a $d$-dimensional rectangle of shape $n_1 \times n_2 \times \dots \times n_d$ with $k$ points homogeneously?

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces, convex-optimization, spheres, packing-problem

Given a $d$-dimensional rectangle ("hyper-rectangle"?)

$$A = [0,n_1]\times[0,n_2]\times\dots\times[0,n_d]$$

with $n_1,\dots,n_d\in\mathbb{R}^+$

How to fill it with $k$ points homogeneously? Or alternatively, where to place the $k$ points such that the minimum distance between any two points is maximal?

---

This turned out to be a surprisingly difficult question to answer. I started scribbling, and the solution wasn't even obvious in $d=2$ dimensions, for example for $k=5$.

The solution was sometimes to have $4$ points in the corner of the rectangle and $1$ in the center; and sometimes, if the rectangle was really narrow, to have them in a line along the rectangles longer side, alternating their positions.

[image: Optimal solution for d=2, k=5 for wide and narrow rectangles]

Similarly, here are some solutions for $d=3, k=9$, for a cube-like and narrow a cuboid:

[image: Optimal solution for d=3, k=9 for cube-like and narrow cuboids]

I think "optimal sphere packing" is a large part of this, because we're technically packing hyper-spheres of an unknown radius $R$ to fill up $A$ perfectly.

---

I have tried solving it using Operations Research, specifically Quadratic Optimization. Let's call the variables $x_1,\dots,x_k\in\mathbb{R}^d$, with $x_{im}$ being the $m$'th coordinate of the $i'th$ variable. Then the optimization problem is:

$$\begin{align}&\max{R} \\
\text{s.t.}\qquad &\forall i \in \{0,\dots,k\}:\quad x_i \ge 0\\
&\forall i \in \{0,\dots,k\}\quad\forall m \in \{0,\dots,d\}:\quad x_{im} \le n_m\\
&\forall i \in \{0,\dots,k\}\quad\forall j \in \{i+1,\dots,k\}:\quad ||x_i - x_j||_2^2 \ge R^2 \\
\end{align}$$

Where the first two sets of conditions ensure that the points are in $A$, and the third set of conditions ensure that each pair of points is at least distance $R$ away from each other. In the optimal sphere packing, each "neighbouring" point will be exactly distance $R$ away, and every other point will be distance $\ge R$ away from each other.

Of course, since $R > 0$, the objective is equivalent to $\max{R^2}$. However the problem is still quadratic because of the $||x_i - x_j||_2^2$ terms.

---

I have tried solving this optimization problem for small cases, namely $d=2$ and $n$ is some small whole number with the [Lagrange multiplier method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), however, the issue quickly gets quite large.

---

Since if $X = (x_1,\dots,x_k)$ is a solution, then any reordering of $X$ is also a solution; it might be smart to also use some kind of ordering condition, like $x_{1j} \le x_{2j} \le \dots \le x_{dj}$ for some $j$, although this might lead to infeasibility.

---

Maybe there is also another way to solve this problem, with some kind of smart insight.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a sphere packing problem. To fit $k$ points into $[0,n_1]\times [0,n_2]\times \cdots \times [0,n_d]$ with minimum distance $R$ is the same
as packing $k$ spheres of radius $\frac{R}{2}$
into  $[-\frac{R}{2},n_1+\frac{R}{2}]\times [-\frac{R}{2},n_2+\frac{R}{2}]\times \cdots \times [-\frac{R}{2},n_d+\frac{R}{2}]$. The sphere packing problem is very hard in generally. The problem of finding (and proving) the densest packing in 3-dimensions was posed by Kepler in 1611 and solved in 1998 by Thomas Hales. The problem of packing a box with fixed dimensions seems very hard in general.